# ImportError: cannot import name COMError in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdf-generation

I am trying to convert docx file to pdf with following code

```
import sys
import os
import comtypes.client


wdFormatPDF = 17

in_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
out_file = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2])

word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
doc = word.Documents.Open(in_file)
doc.SaveAs(out_file, FileFormat=wdFormatPDF)
doc.Close()
word.Quit()
```

It is throwing an error

```
ImportError: cannot import name COMError
```

I have installed comtypes package.

I am very new to python, I can not figure out how to resolve this problem.

[Edit]

Stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "converttopdf.py", line 3, in <module>
    import comtypes.client
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/comtypes-1.1.2-py2.7.egg/comtypes/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from _ctypes import COMError
ImportError: cannot import name COMError
```

Comment: instead of `import comtypes.client` try `import comtypes`. comtypes.client only imports the client package. The COMError might be elsewhere

Comment: @Craicerjack still getting same error

Comment: how did you install comtypes?

Comment: Downloaded `comtypes-1.1.2` and then `python setup.py install`

Comment: can you include the stack trace?

Comment: included in question

Comment: What's your OS? COMtypes is for Windows only.

Comment: @sarvesh I'm afraid COMtypes wont work then. I wrote an answer explaining this. Apologies that it doesn't explain how you could do this, but I'm not personally familiar with any tools that would help.

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately COMTypes is designed for Windows, not Linux.

> comtypes allows to define, call, and implement custom and dispatch-based COM interfaces in pure Python. It works on Windows, 64-bit Windows, and Windows CE.

[Source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/comtypes)

You'll need to find another way to do your conversion, likely through another library.

Comment: And what is the other way??