# ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Tags: python, error-handling

```
import os
import glob
import comtypes.client

from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
 
 
def docxs_to_pdf():
    """Converts all word files in pdfs and append them to pdfslist"""
    word = comtypes.client.CreateObject('Word.Application')
    pdfslist = PdfFileMerger()
    x = 0
    for f in glob.glob("*.docx"):
        input_file = os.path.abspath(f)
        output_file = os.path.abspath("demo" + str(x) + ".pdf")
        # loads each word document
        doc = word.Documents.Open(input_file)
        doc.SaveAs(output_file, FileFormat=16+1)
        doc.Close() # Closes the document, not the application
        pdfslist.append(open(output_file, 'rb'))
        x += 1
    word.Quit()
    return pdfslist
 
def joinpdf(pdfs):
    """Unite all pdfs"""
    with open("result.pdf", "wb") as result_pdf:
        pdfs.write(result_pdf)
 
def main():
    """docxs to pdfs: Open Word, create pdfs, close word, unite pdfs"""
    pdfs = docxs_to_pdf()
    joinpdf(pdfs)
 
main()
```

I am using jupyter notebook and it throw an error what should I do :
[this is error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP987.png)

I am going to convert many .doc file to one pdf. Help me I am beginner in this field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: cannot import name COMError in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161560/importerror-cannot-import-name-comerror-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the dependencies installed in your environment. You can use pip to install comtypes.client, simply pass this in your terminal:

```
pip install comtypes
```

You can download _ctypes from sourceforge:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/ctypes/files/ctypes/1.0.2/ctypes-1.0.2.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=deac-fra

Using docx2pdf does seem easier for your task though. After you converted the files you can use PyPDF2 to append them.