# import error of comtypes in linux whil using pyttsx3 module

Tags: python, linux, pyttsx3

I am having an issue in the pyttsx3 module while using it in linux(raspberrian).When I use the module it gives an error in the following line:`engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')`

the error is:

```
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/indian53/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/sapi5.py", line 1, in <module>
    import comtypes.client  # Importing comtypes.client will make the gen subpackage
  File "/home/indian53/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/comtypes/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from _ctypes import COMError
ImportError: cannot import name 'COMError' from '_ctypes' (/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-39-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so)
```

I also tried

```
pip install ctypes
```

but got the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ctypes
```

edit-
This is the code of the file I am working in

```
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[0].id)

def speak(audio):
    engine.say(audio)
    engine.runAndWait()

def respond(q):
    print(q)
    speak(q)

    
def takecommand(t):
        r = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.2)
            print("listening...")
            audio = r.listen(source)
            print("recognizing...")
        try:
            global query
            query = r.recognize_google(audio)
            query = query.lower()
            print(query)
        except Exception as e:
            if t == 1:
                respond("Sorry, can you repeat that?")
            takecommand(1)
        return str(query)

print("hello world")

respond("happy life")

q = takecommand(1)
```

I would appreciate if someone could help

**Don't forget I am working on linux and this is working fine on windows**

**Please don't mark this question as duplicate because other answer didn't help**

Comment: Which other answer didn't help?  This one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71911149/importerror-cannot-import-name-comerror-from-ctypes-usr-lib-python3-7-li

Comment: Yes, exactly I tried this but didn't help

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the `espeak` driver may have to be used in place of `sapi5`:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238666/python3-7-pyttsx3-no-module-named-pyttsx3
- https://pyttsx3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/engine.html